# Implication of a Japanese sentence

Tags: definitions

I was wondering if there is any context implied by a sentence like "6時に起こしてください。"

I have read it translated as "Please wake me up at 6." But is "me" implied? Could it also mean "Please (will you) wake up at 6."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that there is technically some ambiguity, although slightly wrong in your interpretation. In a sentence like ６時に起こしてください it's basically implied that you mean *yourself*, as in the provided translation ("Please wake me up"). Without context, though, there's no way to be 100% sure. It could be a request to wake up any other person (except the person to whom the request is directed, as in "please wake up at 6").

起こす is a transitive verb, so you're asking this person to wake *someone* up. Wake me up, wake Jim up, wake Mary up, anyone. In Japanese this would be more explicitly stated with を, as in "６時にジョンを起こしてください。"

If you want *that person* to get up at 6, you would use ６時に起きてください. 起きる is an intransitive verb, so it has a meaning closer to the simple "wake up" in English, as in "I woke up at 6." Notice the lack of a direct object. "I woke up at 6" does not imply that you woke someone else up -- it only refers to you, the speaker.

Comment: Ah thank-you, a good explanation of Transitive verbs is on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb#Other_languages